# Using MS Access Database Across Network Share

Tags: ms-access

We have a database with a fairly large table (300+k rows) that needs to be shared by a very small group of people (less than 5).

We previously attempted to have the table shared through Access Web Database (SharePoint 2010, so this was using SharePoint lists), but this quickly became a nightmare scenario as our morning process to load a daily inventory report into this table ran for 3+ hours using SharePoint once the inventory became significantly high. We have reverted to sharing the reports database across a network share, and the person who needs this inventory data for a different job function uses a separate front-end.

The issue we have is that when the one guy has his separate front-end open, which links to one table in the reports database, no one else can connect to the reports database; not even for read-only access.

What can be done to allow proper multi-user access? I've checked every record locking property I can think of, and still can't make anything work.

*(I have to say that there are no viable alternatives to this setup. Even though we recently upgraded to SharePoint 2016 / Office 365, IT refuses to upgrade Access Web Services; so we won't have any access to SQL server, period.)*

Answer (score 0):

The report property sheet has a setting to lock, or not lock the table. simply change that setting, and other users can then edit data, or view the report.

Comment: There aren't any reports involved on the smaller client. It's primarily just a single form which opens the linked table and has a bunch of filtering controls. As mentioned I already checked all the possibile record lock settings. When his database is open the other reports database can't be opened from any other link.